# How to clear and then redraw a quartz drawing

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, erase

I'm making a complex drawing using quartz based on passed in information.  The only part I haven't been able to figure out is how do I clear the lines, rectangles, etc that I've already drawn?  Basically, I want to erase the whole drawing and just draw it again from the new data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you set your `UIView`'s [`clearContextBeforeDrawing`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clearsContextBeforeDrawing) property to `YES`, then the system should take care of filling its area with its `backgroundColor` before calling its `drawRect:` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear something that's not tracked as part of the current state, it's probably less expensive to just release your old context and start a new one.

Comment: Can I do that for just that UIView instance?  If so, how?

Comment: If you have a UIView then you have a drawRect implementation, so it's not going to draw anything you haven't explicitly told it to.

Comment: That is true, I use the drawRect function to draw my shapes.  How do I make use of that to clear and redraw?

Comment: I think you would probably be better off spending some quality time with the documentation. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html